# HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE) from STA Thread

Tags: c#, com, quickbooks

I'm using Quickbooks SDK and I'm trying to cast sessionManager.getResponse(0) to IResponse. However I am met with:

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 
'Interop.QBFC7.IResponse'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the 
COM component for the interface with IID '{2EA0ED7C-01D5-4CCC-B545-AC3D68D3CA81}' failed 
due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 
0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

From looking around on SO I have found that this error is usually solved by creating a STA thread and putting the code inside of that. Also, I am doing this from a windows form. I tried to do that but I can't get it to work. Here are some code snippets:

```
//Creating the thread and starting it
backgroundThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Method));
backgroundThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
backgroundThread.Start();

//inside Method()
SessionManager sessionMgr = SessionManager.getInstance();

IMsgSetRequest msgset = sessionMgr.getMsgSetRequest();
msgset.ClearRequests();
msgset.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue;

ICustomerQuery query = msgset.AppendCustomerQueryRq();
query.metaData.SetValue(ENmetaData.mdMetaDataOnly);
if (sessionMgr.doRequests(ref msgset))
    return;
//This is the offending line
IResponse resp = (IResponse)sessionMgr.getResponse(0);
int count = resp.retCount;
```

What is the correct way to cast sessionMgr.getResponse(0) to IResponse?

Comment: The main thread of a Winforms app is already STA.  A very common reason for this exception is DLL Hell, the version of the component that you use at runtime isn't the same as the one you compiled with.

Comment: Could this error be caused by the fact that I migrated this project from VS 2005 to VS 2010?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a wrapper or helper class for the SDK? I've never seen SessionManager.getInstance() before. Here's some sample code I threw together that I would use. I setup a WinForm with just a button.

```
using QBFC12Lib;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create a new thread and start it
    Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Method));
    backgroundThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    backgroundThread.Start();
}

private void Method()
{
    QBSessionManager sessionMgr = new QBSessionManager();
    sessionMgr.OpenConnection2("AppID", "AppName", ENConnectionType.ctLocalQBD);
    sessionMgr.BeginSession("", ENOpenMode.omDontCare);

    IMsgSetRequest MsgRequest = sessionMgr.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 12, 0);
    MsgRequest.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue;

    ICustomerQuery query = MsgRequest.AppendCustomerQueryRq();
    query.metaData.SetValue(ENmetaData.mdMetaDataOnly);

    IMsgSetResponse MsgResponse = sessionMgr.DoRequests(MsgRequest);

    if (MsgResponse != null && MsgResponse.ResponseList != null)
    {
        IResponse response = MsgResponse.ResponseList.GetAt(0);

        MessageBox.Show(response.retCount.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that and I got HRESULT: 0x80040300 which means that I am attempting to retrieve the value before it has been set.

Comment: I just created a WinForm application and added a button and used the code that I edited above. I was able to get back the number of customers in my QuickBooks file. Are you using any other libraries that wrap the QB SDK?